# Alternatives to for loop and cross dataset subsetting. (..using higher order functions or alternative data structures)

Tags: r

I'm running discrete-event-simulations in R. The "heart" of my algorithm does the following (Pseudocode):

> 1) Iterate over `events`
>
> a) Change `event[i]` depending on `resources`
>
> b) Change `resources` depending on outcome of step a)

The following reproducible example catches the main aspects:

Generate some data:

```
set.seed(4)
n <- 3
nr_resources <- 2

events <- data.frame(
  t = as.integer(trunc(cumsum(rexp(n)))),
  resource = NA,
  worktime = as.integer(trunc(runif(n)*10))
)

resources <- data.frame(
  id = 1:nr_resources,
  t_free = 0L
)
events
resources

# > events
# t resource worktime
# 0       NA        2
# 4       NA        8
# 5       NA        2
# > resources
# id t_free
#  1      0
#  2      0
```

Now we can simulate dispatching of resources:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  events$resource[i] <- resources$id[resources$t_free <= events$t[i]][1]
  resources$t_free[events$resource[i]] <- events$t[i] + events$worktime[i]
}

events
resources

# > events
# t resource worktime
# 0        1        2
# 4        1        8
# 5        2        2
# > resources
# id t_free
#  1     12
#  2      7
```

This approach works fine but there are a number of drawbacks I'd like to eliminate. Since `events` and `resources` are split in two datasets, there is quite a few subsetting (search and replace) going on across the two datasets. This is not really readable. And in the real application it even becomes the performance bottleneck. (..of course the real example is quite a bit more complicated..)

**Therefore I ask myself if there are better ways to accomplish this task in R.**

I thought about replacing the for-loop with a common higher-order function but did not come to any results.

- The typical R `lapply`-approach doesn't work because `lapply` is not built for this iterative changes in the input data. (As far as I can see..)
- My task looks a bit like the `Reduce` pattern. Since `Reduce(sum, 1:3, accumulate = TRUE)` uses intermediate results and also preserves them, I thought I could use the `Reduce` function but did not achieve any results.

I also thought about restructuring my data but with no success till now.

### What I tried in detail

**On the *algorithmic* side:**

Failing approach with `lapply`:

```
l <- list(events = events, resources = resources)
l <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  l$events$resource <- l$resources$id[l$resources$t_free <= l$events$t][1]
  l$resources$t_free[l$events$resource] <- l$events$t + l$events$worktime
  return(l)
})

l$events
l$resources
```

The result becomes:

```
# $events
# t resource worktime
# 1 0        1        2
# 2 4        1        8
# 3 5        1        2
# 
# $resources
# id t_free
# 1  1      7
# 2  2      0
```

Intermediate changes to resources are lost and therefore always resource 1 gets booked.

---

Failing approach with `Reduce`:

```
l <- list(events = events, resources = resources)
l <- Reduce(function(l) {
  l$events$resource <- l$resources$id[l$resources$t_free <= l$events$t][1]
  l$resources$t_free[l$events$resource] <- l$events$t + l$events$worktime
  return(l)}, l, accumulate = TRUE)
```

This fails with

> Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])

---

**On the *data* side:**

The other approach I can think of is to *change the data* to be represented in one dataset. For example by multiplying the events by the number of resources. I tried the following:

```
data <- merge(events, resources)
data <- data[order(data$t), ]
data

# t resource worktime id t_free
# 0       NA        2  1      0
# 0       NA        2  2      0
# 4       NA        8  1      0
# 4       NA        8  2      0
# 5       NA        2  1      0
# 5       NA        2  2      0

for (i in seq_along(data)) {
  if ( is.na(data$resource[i])) {
    data$resource[data$t == data$t[i]] <- data$id[data$t_free <= data$t[i]][1]
    data$t_free[data$id == data$resource[i]] <- data$t[i] + data$worktime[i]
  }
}

data
# t resource worktime id t_free
# 0        1        2  1     12
# 0        1        2  2      7
# 4        1        8  1     12
# 4        1        8  2      7
# 5        2        2  1     12
# 5        2        2  2      7

events <- unique(data[,1:3])
events
# t resource worktime
# 0        1        2
# 4        1        8
# 5        2        2

resources <- unique(data[,4:5])
resources
# id t_free
#  1     12
#  2      7
```

This works as well, but I'm not sure if that leads to better performance, readability and changeability if scaled..

---

So my question is:

Are there any alternatives on the *algorithmic* side or on the *data* side that improves my actual solution(s)?

Comment: Each element in `resources$t_free` is not updated incrementally, it just saves the last sum of `events$t[i]` and `events$worktime[i]` that applied to it. Is this intended?

Comment: @Alexis Yes, that's on purpose: Only the one `resources$t_free` that gets the "job" in one iteration is updated by `events$t[i] + events$worktime[i]` which is the time that resource gets "free" again. Hope this clears things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly prefer your first for-loop,
you should consider using something like `Rcpp::sourceCpp` and migrating your logic to C++.
I think that should be readable and faster.
If you must do it in R,
here's a possibility:

```
t_free <- Reduce(x = 1L:n,
                 init = rep(0L, nr_resources),
                 accumulate = TRUE,
                 f = function(t_free, i) {
                   # which.max will return the location of the first TRUE
                   id <- which.max(t_free <= events$t[i])
                   # R makes a local copy of t_free here
                   t_free[id] <- events$t[i] + events$worktime[i]
                   # return the chosen resource for this "iteration"
                   attr(t_free, "resource") <- id
                   # return the modified copy
                   t_free
                 })

# events$resource column by extracting the resource attribute, igonring init
events$resource <- sapply(t_free[-1L], attr, "resource")
# your resources$t_free column in the last element
resources <- data.frame(id = 1L:nr_resources,
                        t_free = t_free[[n + 1L]])
```